# Creating Dashbord Widgets (using XCode?) based on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, widget

Some time ago I developed an app for a client. It's basically a simple calculator. Because they like it so much they asked me if it would be possible to create dashboard widget with the same functionality based on the iPhone app.

I have never before developed a widget, I only know that they are mostly html + css based, so this raises a few questions for me:

- Is using html + css the only way to create a widget?
- If no:

  - Can XCode be used to create a widget?
  - Is it possible to wrap Cocoa applications into a widget?
- If yes, are there any convenience tools to create a Cocoa-Touch-like look, feel and functionality (especially of tableviews)?

I guess the superquestion to all the above questions would be: Is there any chance I can reuse some parts of the existing iPhone project or do I need to create the widget from scratch?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/Developer/Applications/` directory, you find **Dashcode* which might help you develop a Dashboard widget.

Yes it's mostly HTML+CSS. You can add a Cocoa plug-in, as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Articles/WidgetPlugin.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003051-SW1). However, that Cocoa plug-in can't draw using Cocoa methods onto the webview of the widget.

You can create a webkit plugin as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/Concepts/AboutPlugins.html), which can draw using Cocoa methods onto the webview of the widget. You can package them inside a widget.

However, the Cocoa methods you can use are AppKit methods, not UIKit methods. Specifically, you don't have `UITableView`, you have `NSTableView` which are rather different beast.

The logic parts using Foundation objects can be reused, but I would guess it's a big rewrite. It might be easier and less time-consuming to rewrite everything in terms of html + javascript + css.

I hope Apple add an iOS emulation layer in OS X 10.7, so that you can load an iPhone app to the dashboard. That would be awesome, if Apple can find a way to emulate the touch events nicely...